# View the event list of a cron file

Tags: cron, crontab

I have a relatively complex set of cron jobs running and it would be really useful for me to ask the system for the list of the next n cron tasks that will be performed.

So given a particular crontab i.e (copied and pasted from http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

```
30  0   1   1,6,12  *   A //00:30 Hrs  on 1st of Jan, June & Dec.
0   20  *   10  1-5     B //8.00 PM every weekday (Mon-Fri) only in Oct.
0   0   1,10,15 *   *   C //midnight on 1st ,10th & 15th of month
5   0   10  *   1       D At 12.10 every Monday & on 10th of every month
```

I could get back the list (assuming we start 31st May)

```
Cron jobs in queue:
B 2000 Tuesday
C 0000 Wednesday
B 8pm Wednesday
B 8pm Thursday
```

...ect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not too easy, because `cron` doesn't work that way, i.e. it does not create a "queue" of jobs to be run, but rather has the daemon check for jobs to be run every minute.

One would have to write a script to parse the crontab and rewrite the output. Just a matter of how much time you want to spend.

Here are some alternatives:

- You can have a nice graphical representation of cronjobs with [Gnome-schedule](http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/), because it also translates the crontabs into human readable strings:

[image: Gnome-schedule-example]

- Here is a [Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/193387/cron-job-management) on a similar subject
- [Webmin](http://webmin.com/) has an interface for scheduling and editing cronjobs:

[image: webmin-example]

- There's also a small C# (?) project I found named [crontabviewer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crontabviewer/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [blog post](http://backreference.org/2012/07/07/crontab-calendar-generator/) about a Perl script (`croncal.pl`) that parses crontabs and prints the dates and times of the invocations in a given time range (defaulting to 24 hours starting now).